# Tensorflow: is there a rule to set the port of worker/ps when creating ClusterSpec?

Tags: tensorflow, distributed-computing

When creating `ClusterSpec` in distributed setting, we need to assign `hostname: port` to workers/ps. Is there a rule for choosing `port`? Or is it free to set it to be any number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set it to any available TCP port on the host where you start the `tf.train.Server`.

I usually use port `2222` because it's easy to type (and that number has ended up in a lot of the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/how_tos/distributed/) that I originally wrote).